# jQuery element.closest(…).attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

This script was functioning correctly until I updated Joomla 2.5 to 3.7, php5.6 to php7 and http to https (site in SSL). Jquery is being called correctly.
I don't know which of the updates is affecting the script but I believe it is since I updated to php7:

```
$(function(){
    $('.thumbs img').mouseenter(function(){
        var $bigImage = $(this).closest('.annonces').find('.bigimage');
        $bigImage.attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('180__','600__'));    
    });
});
```

When I'm trying to run it I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: $(...).closest(...).find is not a function

Here is the html:

```
echo '<div class="annonces">';

//images > 768px

if ($book[9])
{
echo '<div class="photosbig"><div class="annoncephoto1" >
<img class="bigimage" src="/annonce/600__' . $book[9] . '" /></div>';
} 
echo '<div class="annonces_legende" style="font-style:italic;">
Passez la souris sur une vignette pour voir l’image apparaître ci-dessus. 
<br />Cliquez pour agrandir l’image.</p></div>';
echo '<div class="annoncephoto2" >';
echo '<div class="thumbs" >';
if ($book[9])
{
echo '<a href="/annonce/' . $book[9] . '" rel="shadowbox">
<img src="/annonce/180__' . $book[9] . '" /></a>';
}
if ($book[10])
{
echo '<a href="/annonce/' . $book[10] . '" rel="shadowbox">
<img src="/annonce/180__' . $book[10] . '" /></a>';
}
if ($book[11])
{
echo '<a href="/annonce/' . $book[11] . '" rel="shadowbox">
<img src="/annonce/180__' . $book[11] . '" /></a>';
}
if ($book[12])
{    
echo '<a href="/annonce/' . $book[12] . '" rel="shadowbox">
<img src="/annonce/180__' . $book[12] . '" /></a>';
}
if ($book[17])
{
echo '<a href="/annonce/' . $book[17] . '" rel="shadowbox">
<img src="/annonce/180__' . $book[17] . '" /></a>';
}
if ($book[18])
{
echo '<a href="/annonce/' . $book[18] . '" rel="shadowbox">
<img src="/annonce/180__' . $book[18] . '" /></a>';
}
echo '</div></div></div>';
}
```

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks#jQuery_JavaScript_Framework: _"This will load the jQuery version 1.11.1 library in **no conflict mode**. This means it is accessed via the `jQuery` namespace, not through `$`."_

Comment: Can we your html?

Comment: Here is an example page:
https://www.lagrandiere-immobilier.fr/annonces-ventes-fr?annoncenumber=402-3979

Comment: If you do `console.log($(this).closest('.annonces'));` is the `.announces` element being logged in the console or does it return `undefined`?

Comment: I apparently do not understand how to get this to work. I pasted your code in the webpage within my function, also outside the function and then again in the web console. All I am getting is
    TypeError: $(...).closest is not a function

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks#jQuery_JavaScript_Framework)... Use `jQuery` instead of `$` -> `jQuery(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supplementary research on **Andreas** suggestion helped me out. Even though it seemed that the jquery library is loaded after the others, there seems to be a conflict with the '$' symbol. I replaced the '$' by 'jQuery' and it functions:

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.thumbs img').mouseenter(function(){
var bigImage = jQuery(this).closest('.annonces').find('.bigimage');
bigImage.attr('src',jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('180__','600__'));    
});
});
```

Thanks for your help to all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you could try to replace `$(this)` with `$(document)` if  the `.bigimage` you're trying to get is outside of the `.thumbs img` scope.

Also what do mean with "htmls"? Could you add the source of the document you're trying to work with?

Comment: Site in https and not htmls. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I did a demo of the structure of your html in my system. I think you have problem in the structure of the html code.
Take a look at the structure i did:

```
<div class="thumbs">
    <div class="img">
        <div class="annonces">
            <div class="photosbig">
                <div class="annoncephoto1" >
                    <img class="bigimage" src="image/logo180__.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note from the above structure that the div with class 'thumbs' has a div with class 'img' before the div with class 'annonces' and so on...
If the structure is not like this, then your code will not work.

Comment: The thumbs div is within the annonces div, which worked before the updates. The annonces div is the englobing div for everything with the foreach loop. I can't use the structure that your are suggesting.